# Which version of linux to practise unix scripting/programming?

Tags: distribution-choice

I was using cygwin, but its frustrating to use. It does not have many programs and is confusing.

I want to get some linux distro in which I can use bash and run most commonly used commands, scripts etc.

EDIT -

Which version of linux is smallest and good enough to learn unix ?
My requirements - it should have all or most programs needed to do bash programming and
scripting. It should NOT be like my cygwin which has no programs like more, lp etc and which keeps on causing installation errors and such.

How is Slitaz in terms of popularity, functionality and development efforts ? I was interested because I was looking for a small sized linux with enough programs to do beginner bash programming/scripting.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Pick one.

Comment: They all can run the same shells and run the same scripts, just pick whichever one you want to use

Comment: @Gilles - Please see my edited question

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried other distros but am very happy with Ubuntu.  No installation issues at all.

Answer (score 1):

For using bash, basically all of them. If you're looking for smallest Damn Small Linux. Maybe Slax could be a good option, because is based in Slackware, one of the anciest, but is you're choice

Comment: Btw, i need gui interface also.

Comment: Both options i gave you have GUI. DSL (Damn Small Linux) has FluxBox and Slax has KDE

Comment: I hope that driver problems dont occur. It might affect my ability to execute some commands, right ?

Comment: That depend of what you're going to do. Driver problems for scripts aren't usually issues for "the first bash script"

Answer (score 0):

Any of them should work; use the one you're most comfortable with.

If you need/want something small, you can begin with Arch Linux or Slackware.

Comment: Please see my edited question.